# Get <title> of external page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing, zapier

I would like to get the content of the `<title>` tag from any specified external page, using JavaScript. Specifically, this is using the [Code app by Zapier](https://zapier.com/help/code/) (vanilla node.js v4.3.2), so additional libraries may not be supported.

`fetch` is [supported](https://zapier.com/help/code-examples/#introductory-http-example)...

```
fetch('http://example.com/')
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.text();
  })
  .then(function(body) {
    var output = {id: 1234, rawHTML: body};
    callback(null, output);
  })
  .catch(callback);
```

Docs state: "Very important - be sure to use callback in asynchronous examples!"

I am learning JavaScript and have been searching and trying various methods for hours. I don't fully understand the *two* functions in the example - I only need to return a "title", not the full body.

I was using an [API designed to get page titles](https://textance.herokuapp.com/), but it seems to be a bit flaky. So I am hoping I can get titles using plain code.

Comment: What is the context? Is this supposed to run in a browser or on the server?

Comment: @FelixKling On the server, not browser.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate! It is specifically related to Zapier, which has specific limitations. Mod should read the question fully before marking as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Node JS then you can use `Request` to get the page, then use [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to parse its contents. To get the title you might do something like this:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('http://example.com/', function (error, response, body) 
{
  if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return
  }
  var $ = cheerio.load(body);
  var title = $("title").text();
});
```

If Cheerio is not available, you could do a more lowtech solution, and just use some simple splits. Not very robust, but might get you what you want.

```
fetch('http://example.com/')
  .then(function(res) {
    var body = res.text();
    var title = body.split('<title>')[1].split('</title>')[0]
  })
  .catch(callback);
```

Comment: `TypeError: body.split is not a function`

Comment: Cheerio not available. Regular method produces the above error, which I take to refer to string definition. But I can't seem to successfully use toString() to fix, which is a solution I read about. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it working, I think - https://pastebin.com/BEyj0WSm

Comment: Your code looks functionally identical to mine. Strange!

Comment: what happens if the <title> tag has an attribute? for example: `<title data-react-helmet="true">`